# Return the user input in another method from another class in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following method in class `Control`:

```java
public void addName() {
    language.specifyArtist();
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

and in class `Artist`:

```
public String getName (){
    control.addName();
    return artistName;
}
```

`artistName` is a data field. Somehow the user input given in the first method is not stored in the return value of the second method. Can somebody explain me how I have to set up the two methods that the first is handling the user input and the second is a getter for the user input?

Comment: Value returned from `sc.nextLine()` method isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: so you mean `String name = sc.nextLine()`, but how do i store then string name in return value artistName?

Comment: You need to return the value of `sc.nextLine` so that it can be assigned to the `artistName` in the method `getName`. But I wouldn't write it that way, because a get method should only return values. I would not implement logic in the method.

Comment: so adding onther methode like. `private void processUserInput() {   String name = control.addName(); }`

Comment: What is the function of `language.specifyArtist()`?

Comment: it should print add name to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to return the result of [`sc.nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) so that it can be assigned to the variable `artistName`:

```java
public String readName() {
    language.specifyArtist();
    return sc.nextLine();
}
```

Also, the name should only be set once. This way I would not write the `readName` method into the get method. The simplest solution would be to call it in the constructor:

```java
public Artist(Control control) {
    artistName = control.readName();
}
    
public String getName() {
    return artistName;
}
```

It would be nicer to pass the name directly in the constructor and thus separate the data from the input:

```java
public Artist(String name) {
    artistName = name;
}
```

Comment: now i have another question.... if i have a method in control `public void displayArtist() {
  language.displayArtistAndSalary(artistName, artistSalary);` and want to do the follwing in my class event: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  Control control = new Control(new Artist(artistName, artistSalary));
  control.displayArtist();` i create a control object in event and within my control object i create an artist with name and salary. after i display the result. can i do this?

Comment: i have changed some thins but your iput stayed in the version as you provided the informations. I tested via `public static void main (String []args) { Artist artist = new Artist(control); System.out.println("Artist: " + artist.getName());}` and got a 0PointerException. Any ideas?

Comment: i have a question about passing parameters. if a am using this `public String readName() {
    language.specifyArtist();
    return sc.nextLine();
}` but instead want to set it up like you proposed, `public Artist(String name) {
    artistName = name;
}` how do i have to set up my method in control to parse the input and initalise in artist the methode from control?